# Returning exact matches with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dataset, url-routing

I'm trying to use ES's [search lite](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/search-lite.html) to query a dataset which contains a key `foo`.  An example of this is:

```
.../_search?q=+foo:bar\-baz
```

Now, my understanding is is that the addition of `+` to the `foo` attribute should make this search return only exactly matches where `foo` is `bar-baz`.  However, I'm finding that I'm also getting other results coming back, for instance `foo-baz` or `baz-baz` etc.

What am I doing wrong here which is causing these other results to be returned?

EDIT: Upon some more research this may be down to using the standard analyzer, and not something else which won't stem and tokenize the term.

Answer (score 0):

- "+foo" means AND field foo
- "-" means not
- default operator is OR

Your query is: field "foo" contains bar OR _all doesn't contains baz

Try this query instead, which is search for phrase "bar-baz":

```
_search?q=foo:"bar-baz"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the field to be analysed you can specify `"index" : "not_analyzed"` in the mapping.  You'll then be able to search for exact matches as desired.

See: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#string